# Installing MacOS Dualboot disk partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, macosx

I have an iMac Intel® Core™ i5-4570R CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4 with Ubuntu 18.04.3. I deleted accidentally macOS while installing Ubuntu, and I can say that I love Ubuntu at this moment.

I have three questions:

1. Nevertheless I need MacOS once again in Dual-boot with Ubuntu. It's kind of tricky but I managed to parted the disk and looks like in the photo. First question: is it right? I can't set a mount point a the moment of parting the disk.
2. When I'm ready with the partition, installing MacOs Sierra (I think I downloaded that), I just need to install it like a Gnu/Linux distro, doesn't it?
3. Do you know a better way of doing it?

This is the `gparted` screenshot:

[image: this is the gparted screenshot]

Thanks for your attention, time and help.

Comment: Are you using sda6 for mac partition?  Not sure but doesn't mac use a different format than ext4, will probably reformat during installation.